# wait for Frame to Load in IE10 Selenium WebDriver IJAVASCRIPTEXECUTER C#

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, webdriver

i am trying to wait for a frame to load before proceeding ...

using IJavaScriptExecuter in C#

```
string returnIframeLoad = @"function(){ if(iframe.load){return true;}}";
IList<IWebElement> Frames = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));

for (int i = 0; i < Frames.Count; i++)
{
           wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
           {
               try
               {
                 return (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(returnIframeLoad );
               }
               catch
               {
                   return false;
               }

           });
}
```

kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a way out:

```
wait.Until<bool>((d) =>{ try { return (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(@"window.onload=function(){};return true;"); } catch { return false; }});
```

window.onload will wait until all frames and resources load